# Find all files in directory and subdirectories while ignoring noncritical exceptions

Tags: c#, error-handling, file-system

I need to get a list of all files supported by some libary (images) in a specified directory and all subderictories.
Root directory of drive might be chosen and in this case I want to skip system folders like "Windows" and "AppData" (some other?).

For such task I can use `Directory.GetFiles()` but problem is - it will stop after getting any exception. In this case I need to just ignore noncritical exceptions and skip folders that cause this exception.

This code looks reasonable to me. But I want to make sure that it is done right.

Please tell me if it should be changed somehow.

```
public static List<string> FindSupportedFiles(string root)
{
    // class from library 
    var optimizer = new ImageOptimizer();

    Queue<string> folders = new Queue<string>();
    List<string> files = new List<string>();

    folders.Enqueue(root);
    while (folders.Count != 0)
    {
        string currentFolder = folders.Dequeue();

        if (currentFolder.Contains(":\\Windows") ||
             (currentFolder.Contains(":\\Users") && currentFolder.Contains("\\AppData")))
        {
            if (folders.Count != 0) currentFolder = folders.Dequeue();
            continue;
        }

        string[] filesInCurrent = null;
        try
        {
            filesInCurrent = Directory.GetFiles(currentFolder, "*.*");
        }
        // Ignore this exceptions
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException) { }
        catch (PathTooLongException) { }
        catch (DirectoryNotFoundException) { }

        foreach (string f in filesInCurrent)
            if (optimizer.IsSupported(f)) files.Add(f);

        string[] foldersInCurrent = null;
        try
        {
            foldersInCurrent = Directory.GetDirectories(currentFolder);
        }
        // Ignore this exceptions
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException) { }
        catch (PathTooLongException) { }
        catch (DirectoryNotFoundException) { }

        foreach (string _current in foldersInCurrent)
            folders.Enqueue(_current);
    }
    return files;
}
```

Comment: Please add the code directly from your IDE. This ensures that the code is correct, at least regarding the scope of your variables.

Comment: Excuse me. Fixed code a bit.

Comment: Are you sure that your code now works as intended or do you need to edit the code in question some more?

Comment: Yes. I tested everything except the way it handles exceptions. Not sure how to properly model cases that lead to this exact exceptions.

Comment: I will not edit code from this point.

Comment: Where does `optimizer` come from?

Comment: Declared it in the beginning of the method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have multiple problems here:

- For the case that an exception is thrown and swallowed you get a `NullReferenceException` at iterating over the `filesInCurrent`.
- If the method would be called using `C:/Windows/` (which is a valid path although it uses a slash instead of a backslash) the `if` condition would never result in `true`.
- The `if (folders.Count != 0) currentFolder = folders.Dequeue();` in addition with the `continue` can lead to problems. Assume the next folder in the queue would be a valid folder like `C:\XFiles` by calling `Dequeue()` and `continue` the folder would silently be swallowed.

  ---
- Fixing the `NullReferenceException` is the easiest task. Just put the iterating over the `filesInCurrent` and `foldersInCurrent` inside the `try` block. By doing this you could place the declaration into the `try` as well.
- Instead of checking if the `currentFolder.Contains()` a not wanted path, you should just refuse to add the paths while iterating over `foldersInCurrent`.
- Instead of having the `optimizer.IsSupported(f)` which had former been a `SomeLib.IsSupported()` you should pass a `Action<string, bool>` which will just handle this. This will make your method future proof if e.g. the decision will be made to use a different lib.
- To overcome the `/` vs `\` problem you should create a `DirectoryInfo()` object using the `root` as parameter. By enqueueing the `FullName` property of the `DirectoryInfo` object any found subdirectory will have the `\` as path separator.
- The code should take advantage of the `List<T>.AddRange()` method instead of iterating over the files and adding them one by one.
- If you later decide to exclude different paths it would be good to extract checking of the validness of the folders to a separate method which could be passed as `Action<string, bool>` parameter as well.
- Parameters of `public` methods should always be ckecked for validness, hence a check for `null` and for emptiness of the `root` should be implemented.
- One could use the `var` type if the right hand side of the assignment makes the type obvious.
- Ommiting braces `{}` although tehy might be optional can lead to hidden and therfor hard to find bugs. I would like to encourage you to always use them.
- Underscore prefixed variablenames are usually only for class-level variables.
- Passing a `root` which doesn't exists should be checked at the beginning of the method as well. By returning early you won't need to `catch` a `DirectoryNotFoundException`.

---

Implementing the mentioned points will lead to

```
public static List<string> FindSupportedFiles(string root, Func<string, bool> isFileValid,Func<string,bool> isFolderValid)
{
    if (root == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("root"); }
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(root)) { throw new ArgumentException("The passed value may not be empty or whithespace", "root"); }

    var files = new List<string>();


    var rootDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(root);
    if (rootDirectory.Exists() == false) { return files; }

    //overcome problem about slash and backslash with using Contains()
    root = rootDirectory.FullName;
    if (isFolderValid(root) == false) { return files; }

    var folders = new Queue<string>();
    folders.Enqueue(root);
    while (folders.Count != 0)
    {
        string currentFolder = folders.Dequeue();

        try
        {
            var currentFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(currentFolder, "*.*").Where(f => isFileValid(f));
            files.AddRange(currentFiles);
        }
        // Ignore this exceptions
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException) { }
        catch (PathTooLongException) { }

        try
        {
            var currentSubFolders = Directory.GetDirectories(currentFolder).Where(f => isFolderValid(f));
            foreach (string current in currentSubFolders)
            {
                folders.Enqueue(current);
            }
        }
        // Ignore this exceptions
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException) { }
        catch (PathTooLongException) { }

    }
    return files;
}

private static bool IsFolderValid(string path)
{

    return (path.Contains(":\\Windows") ||
             (path.Contains(":\\Users") &&
              path.Contains("\\AppData"))) == false;
}
```

and could be called like so

```
var optimizer = new ImageOptimizer();
var supportedFiles = FindSupportedFiles(path, optimizer.IsSupported, IsFolderValid);
```

Comment: Thank you! I see quite a few good practices that I should learn from your advices.

Comment: +1. Regarding `DirectoryNotFoundException`, what if some other process just deleted the folder you're about to scan? I'd also add that the folder validity check is brittle: it also matches things like `C:\WindowsCleaners` and `D:\Userstuff\AppDatareader`.

Comment: Pretty good point. I will look for proper solution later. I thinkg there should be some build in way in .Net.

Comment: @PieterWitvoet good points. Will leave it to the OP to integrate ;-)

Comment: @Heslacher may you also tell me how to find more information about possible problems regarding omission of `{}`?

Comment: Most prominent example: https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2014/02/curly-braces/